# Do the AMD proprietary drivers even work in Ubuntu 13.10/Kernel 3.11?

Tags: drivers, ati, kernel, 13.10, proprietary

I was looking at the system requirements for the latest beta proprietary driver on AMD's website and it said "Linux kernel 2.6 or above (up to 3.10)".

However the unofficial AMD proprietary driver wiki (wiki.cchtml.com) does give instructions on how to install in Ubuntu 13.10, but 13.10 uses kernel version 3.11.

So do any of the proprietary drivers even work in 13.10? Because if the latest beta driver doesn't even support 3.11, will previous versions do?

Answer (score 0):

If you rely on them, don't upgrade.

The supported versions according to AMD are:

- Xorg/Xserver 7.4 and above (up to 1.14)
- Linux kernel 2.6 or above (up to 3.10)
- glibc version 2.2 or 2.3

It's not just the kernel version that will break support for the proprietary drivers

glibc and xorg are above the supported numbers as well.

AMD/ATI has always had terrible support for Linux. If you are a Linux user, i would go with NVIDIA in the future if you want to have a usable box.